# Exclude/Include resource via parameter in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a template that includes 3 resources. Is there a way to programmatically exclude 1 of the 3 resources by using a Parameter of my template?

(that is having the same result that i would get by commenting out the unwanted resource in my template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Since you haven't specified any template, I can only show what I usually do.

```
Parameters:  

  SubnetId:
    Type: String
    Default: ''


Conditions:

  HaveSubnetId:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref SubnetId, '']]   

Resources:

  MyInstance:
    Condition: HaveSubnetId
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
```

In this example, `MyInstance` is going to be created if `SubnetId` is given (i.e., not empty). If `SubnetId` is provided, `HaveSubnetId` will be true.

This is based on [Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) section in a resource declaration.

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Let me triy it , and then i will upvote and approve